using gnome Disk utility to change ownership of ext hard drive
My old Ubuntu computer has crashed but I luckily made encrypted backup on an external hard drive using gnome
Disk utility. I have now a new computer with a shiny new Ubuntu 24.04 but when I try to mount my external backup drive, after giving the encryption password,  I still cannot get permission to view the files since it claims I am not the owner. I am aware that I can change ownership of the drive using the gnome Disk utility. Should this solve the problem straight away? (it warns that using the recursive option may be dangerous), but are there any other ways. I only have one backup and so I want the less dangerous way out of this ownership problem. Any comments?
